# Can't install Mysql-Python on Redhat

Tags: python, mysql, redhat

I'm trying to install MySQL-Python on my RedHat server but have an issue. This is what I do so far :

```
wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/90/5a/ce7bef80825c2188cf507baf57b37516e18dffdb198a6766a597f703059a/MySQL-python-1.2.4.zip#md5=ddf2386daf10a97af115ffad2ed4a9a0
unzip MySQL-python-1.2.4.zip
cd MySQL-python-1.2.4.zip
python setup.py install
```

And this gives me an error who the last line said :

```
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

So I tried to install gcc and python-devel :

```
yum install python-devel
yum install gcc
```

But both packages where already installed.
I have absolutely no idea how to face this issue. (I would like to precise that pip command doesn't work on my system for some reasons that I ignore).

Do you have any idea?
Thanks!

Comment: Try `yum install mysql-devel`

Comment: Thanks, it works !